# Adding std::cout line eliminates memory corruption error

Tags: c++

Here I have a class definition.  It is a little long, but the focus will be on the move constructor and the destructor.  Below the class definition is a short test.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class SharedPtr {
 public:
  SharedPtr() {}

  explicit SharedPtr(T* input_pointer) : raw_ptr_(input_pointer), ref_count_(new size_t(1)) {}

  SharedPtr(const SharedPtr& other) : raw_ptr_(other.raw_ptr_), ref_count_(other.ref_count_) {
    if (ref_count_) {
      ++*ref_count_;
    }
  }

  SharedPtr(SharedPtr&& other) : raw_ptr_(other.raw_ptr_), ref_count_(other.ref_count_) {}

  SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr other) {
    swap(other, *this);
    return *this;
  }

  size_t use_count() const {
    return ref_count_ ? *ref_count_ : 0;
  }

  ~SharedPtr() {
    if (ref_count_) {
      --*ref_count_;
      if (*ref_count_ == 0) {
        delete raw_ptr_;
        delete ref_count_;
      }
    }
  }

 private:
  T* raw_ptr_ = nullptr;
  size_t* ref_count_ = nullptr;

  friend void swap(SharedPtr<T>& left, SharedPtr<T>& right) {
    std::swap(left.raw_ptr_, right.raw_ptr_);
    std::swap(left.ref_count_, right.ref_count_);
  }
};

int main() {

  // Pointer constructor
  {
    SharedPtr<int> p(new int(5));
    SharedPtr<int> p_move(std::move(p));
    assert(p_move.use_count() == 1);
  }

  std::cout << "All tests passed." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If I run the code I get an error message indicating memory corruption:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0000000001e3dc0f ***
======= Backtrace: =========
...

======= Memory map: ========
...

Aborted (core dumped)
```

We may suspect something is wrong with the move constructor: if we move from a `SharedPtr` and then later destruct that `SharedPtr`, it will still destruct as if it were an "active" `SharedPtr`.  So we could fix that by setting the `other` object's pointers to `nullptr` in the move constructor.

But that's not the interesting thing about this code.  The interesting thing is what happens if I don't do that, and instead simply add `std::cout << "x" << std::endl;` to the move constructor.

The new move constructor is given below, and the rest of the code is unchanged.

```
  SharedPtr(SharedPtr&& other) : raw_ptr_(other.raw_ptr_), ref_count_(other.ref_count_) {
    std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
  }
```

The code now runs without error on my machine and yields the output:

```
x
All tests passed.
```

---

So my questions are:

- Do you get the same results as I do?
- Why does adding a seemingly innocuous `std::cout` line cause the program to run "successfully"?

Please note: I am not under any sort of impression that *error message gone* implies *bug gone*.

Comment: It runs "successfully" because that's what "undefined behavior" means. It means the program could crash, could run successfully, or could do something different each time you run. You have a bug that results in undefined behavior, and all bets are off. P.S. Your move constructor should clear out everything from the moved-from object. Use your debugger to understand why. I am ignoring several other issues with the shown code, but that's the most obvious reason for undefined behavior. After a move constructor finishes, you have two objects with exact same data. Kaboom.

Comment: In the move constructor, you need to set the `other`'s members to `nullptr`.

Comment: *Why does adding a seemingly innocuous std::cout line cause the program to run "successfully"?* -- Because by changing the binary image of the program when introducing (or removing) lines of code, you are moving the bug to another place in your program (and sometimes hiding the bug).  That's why you always should debug the program in its "broken" state, and never think that adding/removing irrelevant lines of code actually fixes the problem.

Comment: What's interesting is I tried adding other random lines of code and it didn't make the error go away.  Or maybe that's not really that interesting. Anyway, that's the rough conclusion I came to as well.

Comment: @Apollys -- Basically it's this -- if a C++ programmer cannot explain coherently why a bug is fixed, the bug is not fixed.  I've seen some junior programmers proclaim that "the bug is fixed" and the reason being "the bug doesn't show up any more since I added class X" (which really had nothing to do with the actual problem).  Then I or someone else would say "put the code back to the way it was, and **really** fix the bug".  So in your case, I would have said "remove that cout line, reproduce the bug, and really fix the issue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bolov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427533/4955498) explains the cause of the undefined behavior (UB), when the move constructor of `SharedPtr` does not invalidate the moved-from pointer.

I disagree with bolov's view that it is pointless to understand UB. The question why code changes result in different behavior, when facing UB, is extremely interesting. Knowing what happens can help debugging, on one hand, and it can help intruders intrude the system, on the other.

The difference in the code in question comes from adding `std::cout << something`. In fact, the following change also makes the crash go away:

```
{
    SharedPtr<int> p(new int(5));
    SharedPtr<int> p_move(std::move(p));
    assert(p_move.use_count() == 1);
    std::cout << "hi\n"; // <-- added
  }
```

The `std::cout <<` allocates some internal buffer, which `std::cout <<` uses. The allocation in `cout` happens only once, and the question is if this allocation happens before or after the double free. Without the additional `std::cout`, this allocation happens after the double free, when the heap is corrupted. When the heap is corrupted, the allocation in `std::cout <<` triggers the crash. But when there is a `std::cout <<` before the double-free, there is no allocation after the double-free.

Let's have few other experiments to validate this hypothesis:

1. Remove all `std::cout <<` lines. All works fine.
2. Move two calls to `new int(some number)` right before the end:

   ```
   int main() {
     int *p2 = nullptr;
     int *cnt = nullptr;
     // Pointer constructor
     {
       SharedPtr<int> p(new int(5));
       SharedPtr<int> p_move(std::move(p));
       assert(p_move.use_count() == 1);
     }
     p2 = new int(100);
     cnt = new int(1); // <--- crash
     return 0;
   }
   ```

   This crashes, since the `new` is attempted on a corrupted heap.

   ([you can try it out here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tLY9RfCs4OhOEKYL))
3. Now move the two `new` lines to slightly up, right before the closing `}` of the inner block. In this case, the `new` is performed before the heap is corrupted, so nothing triggers a crash. The `delete` simply puts the data in the free list, which is not corrupted. As long as the corrupted heap is not touched, then things will work fine. One can call `new int`, and get a pointer of one of the lately released pointers, and nothing bad will happen.

   ```
    {
       SharedPtr<int> p(new int(5));
       SharedPtr<int> p_move(std::move(p));
       assert(p_move.use_count() == 1);
       p2 = new int(100);
       cnt = new int(1);
     }
     delete p2;
     delete cnt;
     p2 = new int(100); // No crash. We are reusing one of the released blocks
     cnt = new int(1);
   ```

   ([you can try it out here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f8QPCamurHW7YI1S))

   The interesting fact is that the corrupted heap can be undetected to much later in the code. The computer may run millions of unrelated lines of code, and suddenly crash on a completely unrelated `new` in a completely different part of the code. This is why sanitizers and the likes of [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) are needed: debugging memory corruption can be practically impossible to debug otherwise.

Now, the really interesting question is "*can this be exploited more than for denial of service?*". Yes it can. It depends on the kind of object that is destroyed twice, and what it does in the destructor. It also depends on what happens between the first destruction of the pointer, and its second free. In this trivial example, nothing substantial seems to be possible.

Comment: Awesome!  This is really the type of answer I was hoping for, but I never thought I would get it!

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPtr(SharedPtr&& other) : raw_ptr_(other.raw_ptr_), ref_count_(other.ref_count_) {}
```

When you move the moved from object remains the same. This means that at some point in your program you will `delete` `raw_ptr_` twice for the same memory. The same for `ref_count_`. This is Undefined Behavior.

The behaviour you observe falls well within Undefined Behavior because that's what UB means: the standard doesn't mandate absolutely any kind of behavior from your program. Trying to understand why exactly happens what happens on your particular compiler and your particular version on your particular platform with your specific flags is ... kind of pointless.

Comment: I guess I'm essentially trying to understand something that isn't meant to be understood.  Okay, I'll just leave it at undefined behaviour and move on.  (It's just my nature to want to understand things... >_< )

Comment: @Apollys yeah, pretty much

Comment: You would have to go to significant effort and there's no guarantee that an analogous situation would ever occur again. It can involve quirks in your compiler, execution pattern, and so on. It's mostly about what subsequent data just happens to wind up at the the address previously used. If a zero happens to land there, a call to `delete` or `free` is harmless. If anything else happens to land there, boom. Perhaps your output code just happens to re-use the same memory location and just happens to leave a zero there rendering the bogus free harmless.

Comment: Michael Veksler has demonstrated that it's actually not so difficult to make sense of this.